# How to color my vimgrep result patterns

Tags: search, vim

When using Vim is there a way that `:grep` or `:vimgrep` will color the patterns returned to the buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for the pattern after you've :vimgrep'd it, Vim will highlight it. Just edit the `:vimgrep pattern files` into `:g/pattern/`.

For a richer solution, try [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more or provide an example for your suggestion? I do not fully understand what you mean with editing `:vimgrep pattern files` into `:g/pattern/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Unix grep:

```
:!grep --color pattern %
```

There may be other solutions using internal grep/vimgrep but this one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) fits your bill?

Comment: I found ack-grep did not bring color too.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- For normal search `/` you can use `:set hls`.
- Or you can use  `:match Search /pattern/`. This will hightlight everything that matches `pattern`.