# Colorizing the output of :make, :grep, etc., in Vim

Tags: vim, makefile, grep, vi

When building my application using the `:make` command in Vim, the output is not colorized. I have configured the makefile to use clang as the C compiler, and when running `make` outside of Vim or when running `:!make`, clang's output is colorized. `:set makeprg` returns `makeprg=make`, just for reference.

I have the same issue with `grep`: when running `:grep`, the output is not colorized; when running `:!grep`, it is. I have tried using the `--color` option with `:grep`, to no avail. `:set grepprg` returns `grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null`.

I've read through [VIM Unix commands printed in color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126575/vim-unix-commands-printed-in-color) and also [How to color my vimgrep result patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703336/vim-how-to-color-my-vim-grep-result-patterns). The former seems to have the opposite problem (i.e. `:!command` output not colorized); the latter doesn't have any alternative to dropping down to the shell, which I don't feel is a "correct" fix for the issue.

Comment: Adding `--color` to `grepprg` breaks `:grep`, here, I'm not sure how to include it in the arguments safely. In CLI Vim, both `:!grep foo *` and `:grep foo *` "drop down to the shell". What didyou try for `:make`?

Comment: Did `:!grep foo *` have colorized output? There are no options for colorizing `clang` output as far as I can see, I was planning on doing some tests by setting colorgcc as my `makeprg` later today, so I will add a comment with the results of that.

I did try setting `makeprg` to  `echo\ -e\ \"\\033[32m\ Hello\ World\"` to see if it would be colorized, and it /was/, which was interesting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that when Vim runs other commands via `:make` or `:grep`, those commands don't get a terminal for their standard output -- in the sense that for them [isatty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)(STDOUT_FILENO) is false -- because Vim is capturing the output on its way to being displayed on the terminal.  On the other hand, when you use `:!make` or `:!grep`, standard output **is** just going to the terminal.

Clang by default and `grep --color=auto` (which is probably how you have it aliased) use the terminalness of stdout to decide whether to colourise their output.  This is convenient in that you get colourful output on your terminal but capture just the text when you redirect output to a file -- all without needing to add extra command line options.

So what you want to do is override these commands' usual smarts so that they always colourise their output.

For `grep`, you can use `--color=always` when it is run via `:grep` within Vim:

```
:set grepprg=grep\ --color=always\ -n\ $*\ /dev/null
```

and depending on your colour settings and version of `grep` this will work well enough.

For clang, you can change your Makefile to use `clang -fcolor-diagnostics` so as to [force colourisation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#opt_fcolor_diagnostics) or more flexibly add an extra variable to `$(CC)` that will be overridden when run via `:make` within Vim:

```
:set makeprg=make\ EXTRA_CFLAGS=-fcolor-diagnostic
```

However (at least with clang 3.0 and vim 7.3) you will find that clang's style of colourisation prevents Vim from picking out filenames and line numbers from the diagnostics, so doing this wrecks the advantage of using `:make` rather than `:!make`.

You may be able to teach Vim to pick out the filenames etc from the surrounding ANSI escape sequences that do the colourisation by adding more entries to Vim's `errorformat` option to match the colourised clang-style diagnostics.  (And similarly with `grepformat` if your `grep` colourisation colours the filenames or linenumbers.)

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much perfect! I saw this initially before your edit, and thought of the same thing as you. I'm going to see if I can come up with a working `errorformat` option, and see if I can add it to this answer as it may help others.

Comment: @welp, if you use `:cw`, then vim does its own colorization of the results in the Quickfix window. Is this sufficient, or maybe I've missed something

Answer (score 1):

When you run `:grep` or `:make` (as opposed to `:!grep` or `:!make`),
the output is not only shown in the terminal,
but also sent to the *quick-fix window*, from which it is processed.
You can access the quick fix windo using the vim-command `:copen`.
The quick fix window is essentially a text file that is opened in read-only mode.
Like in any other text file, colors are not supported in the quick fix file.
Instead, they are represented with escape characters like `[01;34m`.
Therefore, producing colorized output from `make` (or `grep`) will
mess up the output as it is shown in the quick-fix window, even if you can get vim to process it,
and send the cursor to the selected error/warning/find message.

The question whether *the output* is colorized now becomes a little subtle: I suggest that the
terminal output should remain uncolored, but that the quick-fix output should be colorized.
The color scheme in the quick fix window is not defined by any color-indications in the file itself, but in the *syntax highlighting*
of the quick fix window, defined in the file `qf.vim` (`/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/qf.vim` on my computer).
The color scheme defined in `qf.vim` does not add much color to the quick fix window, but the syntax hightlighting
scheme may be extended by creating the file `~/.vim/syntax/after/qf.vim`. I use `cmake` in combination with the
`gnu` and/or the `intel` compilers, and get nice-looking results with the following contents for  `~/.vim/syntax/after/qf.vim`:

```
syn match qBuilt            "Built target *" nextgroup=qTarget
syn match qTarget           ".*$"   contained

syn match qEnteringLeaving  ": \(Entering\|Leaving\) directory *" nextgroup=qdSeparator
syn match qdSeparator       "'"     nextgroup=qdName contained
syn match qdName            "[^']*" contained

syn match qbProgress        "\[ *[0-9]*%\]"
syn match qBuild            "Building .* object"
syn match qWarn             "warning\( *#[0-9]*\|\):"
syn match qError            "error\( *#[0-9]*\|\):"
syn match qRemark           "remark\( *#[0-9]*\|\):"

hi def link qTarget          Constant
hi def link qError           Error
hi def link qWarn            Error
hi def link qRemark          WarningMsg
hi def link qEnteringLeaving Keyword
hi def link qBuild           Keyword
hi def link qBuilt           Keyword
hi def link qdName           Include
hi def link qbProgress       Special
```